# How to host an email gateway/firewall for OVH MX solution?

Tags: email, email-server, mailscanner

We have our emails hosted on OVH.com using their MX plans.
It happens that we want to limit the subscriptions/spam/unwanted mails received by our enterprise's mails.

To add OVH premade spam/virus mail filter, you only need to add dedicated MX records (i.e. mx1.ovh.net).

My idea would be to host my own email gateway to do some custom filtering.

MailScanner could provide such feature on top of Postfix.
However, I am not sure of how to setup this solution. And how to configure Postfix/MailScanner.

**Would you please advice on how to setup this or on alternative solutions ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution picked:

- Postfix configured as relay
- Postfix relay_domains and mynetworks set to your email domain
- Postfix smtp_sasl_auth_enable set true and sasl enabled
- Header check enabled, put all "received" mails to "HOLD" status/queue
- Use postsuper and postfix to get the emails information and move the legit mails to active queue.